# Scala Form, Type mismatch error

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am trying to do CRUD on a Category class:

**categoryEdit.scala.html**:

```
@(cat: Category, myForm: Form[Category])    
@admin(title = "Category") {
  @helper.form(action = controllers.Application.categorySave) {        
    @inputText(myForm("name"))

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
  }
}
```

The **controller** code:

```
public static Result categorySave() {
    // save form data here ...
   return redirect(
      routes.Application.index()
  );
}
```

Entry in Routes file is as below.

```
GET   /saveCategory        controllers.Application.categorySave()
```

I am getting this error:

```
type mismatch; found : play.mvc.Result required: play.api.mvc.Call
```

on this line: `@helper.form(action = controllers.Application.categorySave) {`

What's wrong in my form? I am missing something?

Comment: Can you show your `routes` file ? Have you added the route to `controllers.Application.categorySave` ?

Comment: Well I've the entry in routes file but it doesn't make any difference... :(See the edited veersion....

Comment: Did you imported the routes package? If not try the following: `routes.Application.categorySave()`

Comment: where and how to import routes package? when I use `routes.Application.categorySave()`, it gives following error
`value categorySave is not a member of controllers.ReverseApplicaiton`

Comment: You have defined a GET, shouldn't that be a POST?

Comment: As @adis said, I also think it should be POST: `POST /saveCategory controllers.Application.categorySave()`

Comment: THere should be a difference :( now it is the correct code, do a `clean` and try again..

Answer (score 3):

How about changing your action?

```
controllers.routes.Application.categorySave
```

PS : Mind the **routes** in the route.